# QMainWindow not showing up

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow

I have made a quick test program which doesn't seem to bring up anything when executed. Here is my code:

#### z_lock.h

```
#ifndef Z_LOCK_H
#define Z_LOCK_H

#include <QtGui>

class z_lock : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    z_lock();
private slots:
    void password_check();
    void quit();
private:
    QStackedWidget *book;
    QWidget *page1;
    QWidget *page2;
    QLineEdit *input;
};
#endif
```

#### z_lock.cpp

```
#include "z_lock.h"

z_lock::z_lock(){
    book = new QStackedWidget;

    //page1
    page1 = new QWidget;
    QLabel *label1 = new QLabel("Enter password.");
    input = new QLineEdit;
    QPushButton *goButton = new QPushButton("Go");

    connect(goButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(password_check()));

    QHBoxLayout *layout1;
    layout1 -> addWidget(label1);
    layout1 -> addWidget(input);
    layout1 -> addWidget(goButton);
    page1 -> setLayout(layout1);

    //page2
    page2 = new QWidget;
    QLabel *label2 = new QLabel("Welcome, you're in.");
    QVBoxLayout *layout2;
    layout2 -> addWidget(label2);
    page2 -> setLayout(layout2);

    book -> addWidget(page1);
    book -> addWidget(page2);
    setCentralWidget(book);
}

void z_lock::quit(){
    close();
}

void z_lock::password_check(){
    QString guess = input -> text();
    if (guess == "apple"){
        z_lock::book -> setCurrentIndex(1);
    }
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "z_lock.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    z_lock *that;
    that -> show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Please, any help would do. I have carried out research about everything to do with QMainWindow and still nothing. This will probably be stupidly easy to solve and I'm sorry for such a basic question.

Comment: Please do not update the question "silently" with issues fixed based on an answer. That makes the answer partially invalid. Just leave it with the original question that the answers may have potentially addressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues in your code... Let us start with the most important:

- You are allocating the object in your main.cpp on the heap which is a sort-of issue in itself, but even if you do that, you should use the `new` keyword for that in C++.
- That being said, you really should not allocate it here on the heap: partially because it would leak the memory, but more importantly there is no need for it.

Therefore, replace these lines:

```
z_lock *that;
that -> show();
```

with simply this:

```
 z_lock that;
 that.show();
```

This is pretty much the same issue for your layouts here, too:

```
QHBoxLayout *layout1;
QVBoxLayout *layout2;
```

Please change them to:

```
QHBoxLayout *layout1 = new QHBoxLayout;
QVBoxLayout *layout2 = new QVBoxLayout;
```

Furthermore, you should not include the whole QtGui module like this:

```
#include <QtGui>
```

Just include the classes which you eventually need. Even though this is in some Qt 4 book, this is bad practice.

This method is also useless in your code since it does nothing except wrapping the existing slot:

```
void z_lock::quit(){
    close();
}
```

Also, you may wish to use the `tr()` method for things like this to get translation for other languages:

```
 QLabel *label1 = new QLabel("Enter password.");
```

Comment: I have followed your guidelines but still no change. 1 question for you. Why shouldn't I use * ? When I took an online Qt course, I was encouraged to do so. And I always used it in my other programs where everything works fine.

Comment: @user3700465: because it is needless complexity in your main.cpp. You would need to use additional new, you would need to make sure you do not leak the memory by assign the application object as a parent for instance, and so on. If anyone had taught that for you in an online course for this scenario, tell that person to revise the KISS principles. :)

Comment: I changed my layouts as you told me to and it worked. The only problem I have is that someone else has also said the same thing. I don't know who should get the chosen answer... :(

Answer (score 0):

```
z_lock *that;
that -> show();
```

The problem is `that` is an uninitialized pointer. It doesn't point to a valid `z_lock` instance for you to call methods on.

You need to do either allocate and construct a `z_lock` instance with `new`:

```
z_lock* that = new z_lock;
that->show();
```

Or, more simply, switch to stack allocation:

```
z_lock that;
that.show();
```

The same applies to the "layout" variables in the `z_lock` constructor.

This is an example of why it's a good idea to compile at a high warning level and fix warnings. The compiler can easily notice and point out the invalid use of uninitialized variables.

Comment: This answer does not address all the issues blocking the application from working.

Comment: I didn't take anything from your answer. I reviewed the question after the comment.

Comment: Either way, the heap suggestion is still wrong since it leaks the memory.